# How to obtain all details of a contact in Android

Tags: android, contacts

Given a contact id, I can obtain various contact details (like name, phone, email-id, etc) by making different queries for a each of these fields.

But is there a method to obtain all the details associated with this contact id by making a single query?

Comment: @Octavian: I'm not sure I agree with removing *Android* from the question title.  This seems to be a pretty common occurrence for questions on other technologies.  This may be an editing question for meta

Comment: @ChrisLively I have to admit that you might be right on this one. I will change it back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had to change a bit of the tutorial on [**Content Providers**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) since it referenced deprecated classes, this might help.

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.database.Cursor;

// Form an array specifying which columns to return, you can add more.
String[] projection = new String[] {
                         ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                      };

Uri contacts =  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI;
// id of the Contact to return.
long id = 3;

// Make the query. 
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(contacts,
                     projection, // Which columns to return 
                     null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
                                 // Selection arguments (with a given ID)
                     ContactsContract.Contacts._ID = "id", 
                                 // Put the results in ascending order by name
                     ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. But I'm using 1.6 SDK and ContactsContract seems to works for 2.0 and above. Any solution for 1.6 and below versions of Android

Comment: @frieza Go back and look at that Content Providers tutorial linked to in the top of the answer.  Apparently Anthony took the tutorial and updated it to 2.0 when he posted his answer, but what you need is the original tutorial.

Comment: Er, that was my fault I went ahead and assumed it was the 2.0 SDK, but mbaird is right, the tutorial in the `Content Providers` link should work just fine for you.

Comment: i had problem with projection `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email` android 2.2