# Get E-Mail, ID's and Phone from Contact (not using activity)

Tags: android, javabeans, android-context

My class doesn't have extends Activity or `onCreate()` method. So pass the context parameter from the class which extends Activity to this class:

```
public static void getContactNumbers(Context context) {
        String contactNumber = null;
        int contactNumberType = Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;
        String nameOfContact = null;

            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                    nameOfContact = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    if (Integer
                            .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        Cursor phones = cr
                                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                                        null);

                        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                            contactNumber = phones.getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                            contactNumberType = phones.getInt(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                            Log.i(TAG, "...Contact Name ...." + nameOfContact
                                    + "...contact Number..." + contactNumber);
                            ApplicationConstants.phoneContacts
                                    .add(new ContactNumberBean(nameOfContact,
                                            contactNumber, contactNumberType));
                        }
                        phones.close();
                    }

                }
            }// end of contact name cursor
            cur.close();

    }
```

How can implemented  `ApplicationConstants` and  `ContactNumberBean(nameOfContact, contactNumber, contactNumberType))` these two classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution to nearly the same question - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752242/contacts-picker-retrieving-last-name-first-name-phone-number/5754565#5754565)

Hope it helps :)