# Get only email address from contact list Android

Tags: android

I want to display only those contact names whose email address is present. Otherwise that contact name should not be displayed in List. How can I do this? Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<String> getNameEmailDetails(){
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor cur1 = cr.query( 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                                new String[]{id}, null); 
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) { 
                    //to get the contact names
                    String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.e("Name :", name);
                    String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    Log.e("Email", email);
                    if(email!=null){
                        names.add(name);
                    }
                } 
                cur1.close();
            }
        }
        return names;
    }
```

the above method return an arraylist of names which has email id.

Comment: I am getting contact names and email address in ArrayList. I saw in log cat like this: Name: abc@gmail.com, Email: abc@gmail.com, Name: xyz@gmai.com, Email: xyz@gmail.com, Name: xyz, Email:xyz@gmail.com. Means I am getting mixture of names and email address in contact name :(

Comment: It doesnot gives the name. It only gives the email id

Comment: And don't forget to add "read contacts" permission:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: Use the answer from Marcin, it performs WAY(!) better!

Comment: This method works but it is slow, prefer the answer of Marcin.

Answer (score 123):

Here is my super fast query to pull email addresses.  It is much faster than pulling all contact columns as suggested by other answers...

```
public ArrayList<String> getNameEmailDetails() {
    ArrayList<String> emlRecs = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashSet<String> emlRecsHS = new HashSet<String>();
    Context context = getActivity();
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID };
    String order = "CASE WHEN " 
            + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME 
            + " NOT LIKE '%@%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, " 
            + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME 
            + ", " 
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA
            + " COLLATE NOCASE";
    String filter = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " NOT LIKE ''";
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, filter, null, order);
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // names comes in hand sometimes
            String name = cur.getString(1);
            String emlAddr = cur.getString(3);

            // keep unique only
            if (emlRecsHS.add(emlAddr.toLowerCase())) {
                emlRecs.add(emlAddr);
            }
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }

    cur.close();
    return emlRecs;
}
```

I tried the code provided by 'Agarwal Shankar' but it took about 4 seconds to get contacts on my test device, and this code took about 0.04 sec.

Comment: Ultimate Answer.. Must Use this one

Comment: Super fast, way faster then the other solution.

Comment: This should be the answer. Not the other one. +1

Comment: It is really super fast comparing to non-filter example. Thanks!

Comment: What does the sql command in order variable mean? Especially "THEN 1 ELSE 2" is somewhat confusing.

Comment: I test it and it work for most of the device, but on my LG G3 5.0, this not working!!!

Comment: @ChandraSekhar Tested on my Lollipop devices and it works.

Comment: Is there any way to get the photo of the contact?

Comment: Hi, I wrote same query to get contact names whose sip address is present. But it is not working. I am not able to figure out what content resolver default value for sip address  when sip address is not there

Comment: @douarbou I am not sure if you still need it but I have same issue with LG G3 you can fix it by replacing "NOT LIKE" with "<>" in filter

Comment: This is Really a super fast, You release the headache.

Comment: Does the query run on main thread or does it use a different thread? Is there a problem if it runs on the main thread?

Comment: Can you explain what does your `order` does in this case? I have previously written a function which has pagination on it and I'm not sure where I can insert it there.

Comment: Hi, Along with emails how can i get email type? 
Can you tell me how can i add it in this code?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
          while (cur.moveToNext()) {
              String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

              Cursor emailCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id},null); 
              while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
                      String email = emailCur.getString( emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                      Log.e("Email",name+" "+email);
                  } 
                  emailCur.close();
              }

          }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution.

```
private static final Uri URI_CONTACT_DATA = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS;
private static final String COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY;
private static final String COLUMN_MIMETYPE = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE;

private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
        COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
        COLUMN_EMAIL,
        COLUMN_MIMETYPE
};

private Cursor getCursor() {
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    String selection = COLUMN_MIMETYPE + "=?";
    final String[] selectionArgs = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
    return resolver.query(URI_CONTACT_DATA, PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null);
}
```

The issue is that the table at `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` holds **the entire contact database**. This includes phone numbers, emails, organisations, and even completely custom data, so you cannot use it without filtering with `ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE`. A row in this database holds a value (or values, it has 15 generic columns) related to a certain account, so you might need to group them yourself. I needed this to autocomplete emails, so the format (email per row) was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you can already get the contacts and their email address (if it exists), why don't you just remove the contacts with no email address from your list?

See [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html) for more information on the Android Contacts API.

Comment: Hey thanks IrAndroid. Yes I am doing that only. But I am getting all contact names. Can you please show me some code for that?

Comment: Here's a similar question to what you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205999/android-get-a-cursor-only-with-contacts-that-have-an-email-listed-android-2-0.

Comment: Hey I tried that code given on this link. But I am getting email address. Not name. I want to get contact names if email address is exist. Can you give me some code? So that I can get some Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to get email id of contact from contact list. You need to pass contact id of user in below method and it will return you email id if exists

```
 public String getEmail(String contactId) {
    String emailStr = "";
    final String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE};

    Cursor emailq = managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, projection, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{contactId}, null);

    if (emailq.moveToFirst()) {
        final int contactEmailColumnIndex = emailq.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);

        while (!emailq.isAfterLast()) {
            emailStr = emailStr + emailq.getString(contactEmailColumnIndex) + ";";
            emailq.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return emailStr;
}
```

And also if you want to learn how to get contact list in your app follow this link: [show contact list in app android - trinitytuts](https://trinitytuts.com/get-contact-list-and-show-in-custom-listview-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Declare A Global Variable

```
// Hash Maps
Map<String, String> nameEmailMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Then Use The Function Below

```
private void getEmailIDs() {

    Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    // Loop Through All The Emails
    while (emails.moveToNext()) {

        String name = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String email = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));

        // Enter Into Hash Map
        nameEmailMap.put(email, name);

    }

    // Get The Contents of Hash Map in Log
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : nameEmailMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Log.d(TAG, "Email :" + key);
        String value = entry.getValue();
        Log.d(TAG, "Name :" + value);
    }
    emails.close();
}
```

Remember in the above example the key is email and value is name so read your contents like mahaXXXX@gmail.com->Mahatma Gandhi instead of Mahatma Gandhi->mahaXXXX@gmail.com