# How can i pick a single e-mail address from contacts if i have more than one email in single contact

Tags: android

```
Button btnEditAccount = (Button) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.contacts1);
btnEditAccount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        mpopup.dismiss();
        startActivityForResult(
            new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI
            ),
            REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS
        );
    }
});
```

This is my code now i need to pick one email address from contacts which is having more emails in that contact

Comment: And what is the error ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get only email address from contact list Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117049/get-only-email-address-from-contact-list-android)

Comment: I need to pick the email address from the contacts manually but now i am able to pick all those emails present in a single contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you are already getting all the email in the single list. Now, you can retrieve the particular email address from the list by iterating the list based on the condition for the specific email id. For Example

```
ArrayList<String> listEmail;

for(int i=0; i<listEmail.length(); i++) {

 if(YOUR CONDITION TO GET SPECIFIC EMAIL ID WITH listEmail.get(i)) {
     //DO SOMETHING
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this will not suite for my code because exactly what i need is to pick one email address from the contact which is having more than one email. for ex: I have 4 contacts and each contact having three emails(home,work,other,....)so i need to pick exactly one e-mail address from that contact...so please let me know the solution

Comment: I think the hierarchy is like this, suppose ContactsList contains list of two contacts xyz and abc. Now, xyz having three type of list homeEmail, workEmail and otherEmail and you want suppose workEmail of xyz. I am right??

Comment: If really you want to do.. you have to use nested for loop to fetch the contacts from home ot work or others.. I have checked it and discussed with others also, there is no method to get direct.

Comment: Is there any option to go into the contact and select the mail address instead of directly clicking on the contacts and get email