# Get only contacts with e-mail address in android

Tags: android, email

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117049/get-only-email-address-from-contact-list-android) and got a working code to get names and e-mails of contacts who's emails exist (only those with e-mail address). However, i'd like to add phone number there aswell, if one exists. Currently i'm still learning and can't quite grasp the whole concept of Cursors and why am i not able to get phone number with my code

```
        private void displayContacts() {
        ArrayList<String> namesmails = getNameEmailDetails();
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<namesmails.size();i = i+2) {
            //namesmails[0] == name && namesmails[1] == phone && namesmails[2] == email
            String name = namesmails.get(i);
            String mail = namesmails.get(i+1);
            listDataHeader.add(name);
            List<String> currentName = new ArrayList<String>();
            currentName.add(mail);
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(counter), currentName);
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
    /*
        This method gathers the information about contacts
     */

    public ArrayList<String> getNameEmailDetails(){
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor cur1 = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) {
                    //to get the contact names
                    String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.e("Name :", name);
                    String phone=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.e("Nr: ",phone); //Here is e-mail instead of phone nr?!?!
                    String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    Log.e("Email", email);
                    if(email!=null){
                        names.add(name);
                        names.add(email);
                    }
                }
                cur1.close();
            }
        }
        return names;

    }
```

As i pointed out with a comment, the contact phone number is not displayed, however the e-mail is. What should i change so the contact phone would also be displayed.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820544/2252830)

Comment: you mean its not displayed on log, or not added in names arraylist?

Comment: @subhash It takes the wrong element apparently. String phone = email for some reason.

Comment: again see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820544/2252830)

Comment: I only need contacts who has email.

Comment: so remove those who doesn't have email, whats the problem? have you notice how fast is my algorithm where you execute ONE query instead of yours where you execute 1 + N where N is number of contacts with an email?