# Android Contact Check if a contact has an email id

Tags: android, email, cursor, contacts, contactscontract

I got the way to check if a contact has a phone number by using
HAS_PHONE_NUMBER

```
ContentResolver ContntRslverVar = getContentResolver();
Cursor ContctCorsorVar = ContntRslverVar.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

while (ContctCorsorVar.moveToNext())
{

    if (Integer.parseInt(ContctCorsorVar.getString(ContctCorsorVar.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
    {

    }
}
```

Similary is der a way to check email ? like 
HAS_EMAIL

```
if (Integer.parseInt(ContctCorsorVar.getString(ContctCorsorVar.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_EMAIL))) > 0)
{

}
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117049/get-only-email-address-from-contact-list-android#10117750

Comment: Yes I did in that way. But I felt, if I check before email query, using something like HAS_EMAIL, it wil decrease number of query and wil be faster.

Comment: you can do it faster then the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117049/get-only-email-address-from-contact-list-android#10117750 in just one additional query instead of one query per contact, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes exactly., Need that as a coloumn index of query

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can run a single query to get all the contact-ids that have emails, store those ids in a set, and use that as an "HAS_EMAIL" reference:

```
Set<Long> hasEmail = new HashSet<>();
// The Email class should be imported from CommonDataKinds.Email
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Email.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Email.CONTACT_ID }, null, null, null); 
while (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
    hasEmail.add(cursor.getLong(0));
}
if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.close();
}

// now you can check if a contact has an email via:
if (hasEmail.contains(someContactId)) {
    // do something
}

// or iterate over all contact-ids that has an email
Iterator<Long> it = hasEmail.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Long contactId = it.next();
    // do something
}
```