# how to get email address from contact list?

Tags: java, android, email, android-contacts

how to get email address from contact list.below code I got number and name and display on list.but I want number,name and email address so pls check below code

```
 ContentResolver contactResolver = context.getContentResolver();

    Cursor c = contactResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER }, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()>0)
        while ( cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            // String photoUri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            //  String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

            Log.e("TAG",  " Name: " + displayName+"==>phone Number==>"+number);

            contactNameArrayList.add(displayName);
            contactNumberArrayList.add(number);

            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {


                Cursor pCur = contactResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contactId }, null);


                while (pCur.moveToNext())
                {
                    String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String type = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                    String s = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), Integer.parseInt(type), "");

                   // Log.e("TAG", s + " phone: " + phone);

                }
                pCur.close();
            }

            Cursor emailCursor = contactResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    null, null, null);

            while (emailCursor.moveToNext())
            {
                String email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                int type = emailCursor.getInt(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                String s = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.getTypeLabel(context.getResources(), type, "");

                Log.e("TAG", s + " email: " + email);
            }

            emailCursor.close();

        }  cursor.close();


    Log.e(TAG,"contactNameArrayList sIZE==>"+contactNameArrayList.size()+"contactNumberArrayList size==>"+contactNumberArrayList.size()+"contactEmailAddressArrayList size==>"+contactEmailAddressArrayList.size());

}
```

I create three array for name and number and email id but above code I got only mobile and  name.when I am add name and mobile no in array so simultaneously store email id particular mobile no in email id array.so pls help ...

Comment: Duplicate questions with lot of answers. [how to get email address rom contact list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117049/get-only-email-address-from-contact-list-android)

Answer (score 0):

### You can get Email from contact using this

```
public List<String> getEmail(int contactId) {
    List<String> emailStr = new ArrayList<String>();
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
        String email = emailCur.getString(
                emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));


        emailStr.add(email);
        System.out.println("Email " + email );
    }
    emailCur.close();
    return emailStr;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code to get multiple numbers and email from one contact and all contacts from phonebook.

```
private void getContactsFromPhoneBook() {

    String unique_id = ApplicationConstant.phone_id;
    System.out.println("Unique_ID  : " + unique_id);

    Contact_To_Sync contact_to_sync = new Contact_To_Sync();

    List<Contacts> AllContact_toSync = new ArrayList<>();

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

    System.out.println("Contacts Count : " + cur.getCount());

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

        Contacts contacts = null;

        List<String> Phones;
        List<String> Emails;

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {

            contacts = new Contacts();
            Phones = new ArrayList<>();
            Emails = new ArrayList<>();

            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String timeStamp = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP));




                contacts.setContact_id(id);
                contacts.setName(name);

                System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id + " Status : " + timeStamp);

                // get the phone number
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);

                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phone = pCur.getString(
                            pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    System.out.println("phone" + phone);

                    Phones.add(phone);

                }
                pCur.close();


                // get email and type

                Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // This would allow you get several email addresses
                    // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                    String email = emailCur.getString(
                            emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                            emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                    Emails.add(email);

                    System.out.println("Email " + email + " Email Type : " + emailType);
                }
                emailCur.close();


                contacts.setEmails(Emails);
                contacts.setPhones(Phones);

                AllContact_toSync.add(contacts);


        }

        contact_to_sync.setContacts(AllContact_toSync);
        contact_to_sync.setPhone_device_name(unique_id);

        if (!contact_to_sync.getContacts().isEmpty()) {
            Sync_Contacts_To_Server(contact_to_sync);
        }

    }

}
```