# Pick first and last name from contact list

Tags: android

How to get first name and last name from contact list?

Comment: Keep trusting **Google** more!!

Comment: Why dont you just search ones "Android How to get contact info programmatically?"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Contact Manager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html) sample project for code to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String whereName = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
String[] whereNameParams = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
Cursor nameCur = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, whereName, whereNameParams, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
while (nameCur.moveToNext()) {
    String given = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
   String[] str = given.split(' ');
       String fname=str[0];  // FIRST NAME
       String lname=str[str.length-1]; // LAST NAME
}
nameCur.close();
```

for more details see this post [How to get the firstname and lastname from android contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301064/how-to-get-the-firstname-and-lastname-from-android-contacts)