# How to get all the contacts for a given name prefix in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I`m currently developing an android application which is intend to call a user based on the user voice input. That is when user says a name (i.e "John"). i want to retrieve all the contacts from my contact list which contains that name with their contact number (i.e "John Mavel - +94715295296,John Cena - +94715295286, Marine Jone - +94715294568, Josh John Samuwel - +94715297895. etc").  And if there is only one contact with that name i want to make a call directly without giving any suggestions. By now i have implemented a code to make a call for a given hard coded name. and it takes a voice input.

```
            package com.chamika_kasun.voicerecognitionapp;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;
            //import java.util.List;

            import android.net.Uri;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.provider.ContactsContract;
            import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.ContentResolver;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
            import android.database.Cursor;
            //import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.ListView;
            import android.widget.Toast;
            import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
            import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;

            public class MakeCall extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

                public ListView mList;
                public Button speakButton;

                public static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.make_call);

                    speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
                    speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);

                    voiceinputbuttons();

                    // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
                    // if running on AVD virtual device it will give this message. The mic
                    // required only works on an actual android device
                      // Disable button if no recognition service is present
                    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
                    if (activities.size() == 0)
                    {
                        speakButton.setEnabled(false);
                        speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
                    }

                }


                public void voiceinputbuttons() {
                    speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
                    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                }

                public void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Speech recognition demo");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);

                }

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    startVoiceRecognitionActivity();

                }

                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it
                        // could have heard
                        ArrayList matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));

                        //if (matches.contains("vidudaya")) {

                            String name = matches.toString();
                            String number = "";


                            Toast.makeText(this, "Name : "+name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                            Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,"DISPLAY_NAME = '" + name + "'", null, null);
                            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                String contactId =
                                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                                //
                                //  Get all phone numbers.
                                //
                                Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                    Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                                   number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
            //                      int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
            //                      switch (type) {
            //                          case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
            //                              // do something with the Home number here...
            //                              break;
            //                          case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
            //                              // do something with the Mobile number here...
            //                              break;
            //                          case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
            //                              // do something with the Work number here...
            //                              break;
            //                          }

                                    Toast.makeText(this, "My Mobile Number : "+number,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                                phones.close();
                               }
                               cursor.close();

                                String url = "tel:"+number;
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
                                startActivity(intent);

                        //}


                        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code retrieves the contact based on the contact name:

```
Cursor contactLookupCursor =
        getContentResolver().query(
                Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                        Uri.encode("Rohan")),
                new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup.NUMBER},
                null,
                null,
                null);

try {
    while (contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()) {
        contactName = contactLookupCursor.getString(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        contactNumber = contactLookupCursor.getString(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.NUMBER));
    }
} finally {
    contactLookupCursor.close();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Try this, and let me know what happen,

Look at 
[ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html)
 class. You can find there all columns you are looking for.

```
 String whereName = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
    String[] whereNameParams = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
    Cursor nameCur = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, whereName, whereNameParams, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
    while (nameCur.moveToNext()) {
        String given = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
        String family = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
        String display = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    nameCur.close();
```

refrence,
[Look at this question How to get the firstname and lastname from android contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301064/how-to-get-the-first-name-and-last-name-from-android-contacts)

[Working-With-Android-Contacts](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts)

Answer (score 0):

You can find contacts with this code

```
String searchName = "john";
String name, number;
String columns[] = new String[] { People.NAME, People.NUMBER };
Uri mContacts = People.CONTENT_URI;
Cursor cur= getContentResolver().query(mContacts, columns, null,null, null);
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
    name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.NAME));
    number = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER));

    if((number!=null) && (name.toLowerCase().contains(searchName.toLowerCase()))){
     Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
//              Add Contact to Search array.
        }
   } while (cur.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this once, It was a bit lengthy but easy...

1. I stored contacts in a string against names.
2. searched string for my required person.

```js
 String contacts = new String();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 1);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 1);
            }
            getContactDetails();
        } else {

            int flag = 1;
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);
            if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
                while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(
                            cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                new String[]{id}, null);
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            contacts= contacts+ name + ":" + phoneNo + "<br>";
                            flag++;
                        }
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (cur != null) {
                cur.close();
            }
        }
        return contacts;
```

This function return a string value...