# How can I get the default phone and SIM contact's ACCOUNT_TYPE and ACCOUNT_NAME?

Tags: android, android-contacts, bulkinsert, accountmanager

I want to get the default phone and SIM ACCOUNT_NAME and ACCOUNT_TYPE.
On some devices, when I try to save a contact, it is not showing in the default Contact app of the device (like SONY or ASUS).
It doesn't work when I try to pass null at ACCOUNT_NAME and ACCOUNT_TYPE, when saving the contact by bulk insertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each device maker puts whatever it wants as the account type and name for the phone's phone-contacts, I've compiled a list for the major makers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44802016/819355

Regarding SIM contacts, almost all makers use: `vnd.sec.contact.sim` as account_type, except OPPO which uses: `com.oppo.contacts.sim`.

If you have any items to add to these lists, please add in comments.

Comment: I think we can use AccountManager to loop the device's accounts and try to find what I need, maybe!

Comment: yes, that's how i got to my list of phone-contacts and sim-contacts

Comment: So how do you get the SIM account-name and account-type? Someone mentioned that he queried ContactsContract.Settings.CONTENT_URI to get it , but I can't see the query: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45875690/878126