# Fetching all details of a contact with the help of contact ID

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I do have contact IDs available with me. Is there a way that I can get all the details of the contact (with the help of the contact ID)?

There was already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205246/how-to-obtain-all-details-of-a-contact-in-android) exist on Stack Over flow regarding the same but the answer seems to be outdated and doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code snippet for fetching all details of contact using contact id.

```
public static ModelContact getContactDetails(final Context context, String contactId) {

        ModelContact contact = new ModelContact();
        contact.setContactId(contactId);

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Data._ID,
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                        ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY,
                        ContactsContract.Data.DATA1,
                        ContactsContract.Data.DATA2,
                        ContactsContract.Data.DATA3,
                        ContactsContract.Data.DATA4,
                        ContactsContract.Data.DATA5,
                        ContactsContract.Data.DATA6,
                        ContactsContract.Data.DATA7,
                        ContactsContract.Data.DATA8,
                        ContactsContract.Data.DATA10},

                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                        + "(" + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' OR "
                        + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' OR "
                        + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' OR "
                        + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' OR "
                        + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')",
                new String[]{contactId}, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                contact.setDisplayName(displayName);
                String rowContactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID));
                contact.setRawContactId(rowContactId);
                String lookUpKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.LOOKUP_KEY));
                contact.setLookupKey(lookUpKey);

                String mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE));
                if (mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                    setPhoneList(cursor, contact);
                } else if (mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                    setEmailList(cursor, contact);
                } else if (mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                    setStructuredName(cursor, contact);
                } else if (mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                    setOrganization(cursor, contact);
                } else if (mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                    setAddress(cursor, contact);
                }
            }

            cursor.close();
        }
        return contact;
    }
```

For more details check the following link.

[ContactHelper.java](https://gist.github.com/piyush-malaviya/c423a5531846fa8143a0432382296a75)

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Looking into it. Thanks

Comment: One question buddy, how do you access label and value of getPhoneList()? When I'm trying to get the label like result.get(indexValue).label it work fine in debugger but android studio trowing error at the time of compilation.

Comment: @SanjayJoshi Did you mean get a label from a ModelContact object.getPhoneList() method? and Can you post the error which you get compilation time?

Comment: @PiyushMalaviya: Can you help me with getting primary number for a contact? When I try to execute "cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_PRIMARY);" in your "setPhoneList" method, it always return "-1" for all numbers (even for the primary number). Is there a way to know the primary number from existing cursor (in setPhoneList method itself)?